# Use of Conditional Operator in C++

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

The below code gives a compiler error:--> **rough.cpp:6:30: error: operands to ?: have different types 'short int' and 'const char*'**

```cpp
int main() {
    for (short i {10}; i <= 100; i += 10) {
        cout<<((i % 15 == 0) ? i : "-")<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**This code compiles without any error or warning:**

```cpp
int main() {
    for (short i {10}; i <= 100; i += 10) {
        cout<<((i % 15 == 0) ? i : '-')<<endl; // error line
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**And shows the below output:**

```
    45
    45
    30
    45
    45
    60
    45
    45
    90
    45
```

**Can anybody please explain what's happening and what's the difference between the two ?**

As I want the expected output to be:

```
-
-
30
-
-
60
-
-
90
-
```

Comment: Perfect situation to use an `if` instead of a `?:`.  For the `?:`, the true-case-expression and false-case-expression need to be the same type.  So the `char` is being promoted to a number for the character value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opeands must have the same type or a common [type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/conditional-operator-q?view=vs-2019):

> If the operands have different types and at least one of the operands
>   has user-defined type then the language rules are used to determine
>   the common type. (See warning below.)

In your first example you have a `string`(`const char*`) which has no common type with int.

While in the second example you have a `char` the can be converted to an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the best solution is the simplest solution. In this case you cannot use the ternary operator ?: because you do not have the same return type. Because your first return is an int the '-' that is your else becomes an int, too.

```
int main() {
    for (short i {10}; i <= 100; i += 10) {
        if(i % 15 == 0)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << '-' << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But the in the 2nd code we are returning `i` and `'-'`, which compiles without any error or warnings !

Answer (score 1):

The operands to the conditional operator have to be either the same type or convertible to some common type. There's a long list of rules about this on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) but what's happening here is that `i`, a `short int` is being converted to a `char`. Also, an `int` and `char const*` do not have a common type and thus give an error.

You want `i` to be printed as a string.

```
((i % 15 == 0) ? to_string(i) : "-")
```

Comment: @Evg Ah, I see. He wants to print strings.